# CKEditor not showing in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am unable to show the CKEditor UI, for reasons unknown at some places. In one view, it works great.. in another it does not, but uses the exact same code as the one that works. Allow me to clarify:

I am going database first, and connecting an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to a database I have running. Then I made a controller, lets call it "news" with the MVC CRUD template, linking it to my model (database). From here the views are compiled for me, and under the "Create" view I would introduce:

```
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.content, new { @class="ckeditor", @id="ckeditorbox"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.content)
    </div>
```

where model.content is the column name in the database (read/write to DB works, so this isn't really the issue anyway). This appears as a blank space in my browser. Inspecting the page with Google Chrome I see that it gets a visibility:hidden attribute for some reason.

Now

If I were to make a new controller with no template (Empty MVC controller) and post the exact same code from the Create.cshtml view into my newly created Index.cshtml then CKEditor would display just fine. Anyone got an idea as to why this is?

I was thinking this was an issue with the ckeditor.js script not being initialized, because the initializing is placed in _Layout.cshtml as:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("addons/ckeditor/ckeditor.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However placing this in the Create.cshtml view does not work either.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As to why CKEditor did not appear on particular pages, I am not sure. The fix for me however was to set:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace('x');
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    ignoreEmptyParagraph = true;
};
```

in the view